# Se puede realizar con wordpress o wix una pagina de internet similar a segundamano.mx o mercado lib re.com?

Tags: wordpress

Estoy buscando hacer una pagina en el cual usuarios puedan publicar sus productos y que otras personas interesadas puedan contactarlo o comprarlo.

En las plataformas wix o wordpress es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Entonces no es una página, es todo un sistema web

Answer (score 0):

En wordpress existen complementos para crear una tienda solo debes de buscar lo, probarlo y configurarlo.
[Plugins de tiendas online](https://www.lomejordewp.com/mejores-plugins-wordpress-tiendas-online/)